# php multidimentional array to mySQL table not all data going in?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and am trying to store it to a MySQL table.

For some reason it is storing some of the data but not all of it I have checked and the `$count` is the correct number of rows and I have checked `$i` to make sure that is is going though every number but it is still not working.

It takes some rows but not others and if I run it again it doesn't even take the same rows.

```
$count = count($my_array);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    mysql_query("   INSERT INTO     tbl_savedSearches(title,content,articleDate,link,userName,webSiteSource)
        VALUES(    
            '".$my_array[$i]['title']."',
            '".$my_array[$i]['content']."',
            '".$my_array[$i]['articledate']."',
            '".$my_array[$i]['link']."',
            '".$my_array[$i]['Username']."',
            '".$my_array[$i]['website']."'  
        )");          
}
```

Could anyone offer any advice on this?

Comment: What does mysql_error() say?

Comment: It's called [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com). Read up about them, and start checking for failure in your code... you're simply assuming nothing will ever fail. `mysql_error()` exists for a reason. USE IT.

Comment: yes, store the query in a string and output the string somewhere before executing. try to manually execute it on mysql server. in the meantime, i'd bet that your 'content' or 'title' fields have some chars you don't want in your db

Comment: To add to @hummingBird, go into PHPMyAdmin if you can and paste your insert statement - play with it there so you can see the error.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the fact that your arrays are multidimensional. It has to do with each different INSERT query. I'm not going to post an answer to this, but I'm going to ask you to read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) carefully instead.